# AutoLayout - Keep Ratio of Image With Horizontal Constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiimageview

I've been trying to implement a timeline of picture (as instagram or facebook).
However, I've been struggling with the ratio of the image.

Here's my xib that contains my Cell :
[image]

I want the picture to keep its ratio and to completely fill the width of the cell.
I've set 4 autolayout constraint on the UIImageView as 0-0 for horizontal constraint and 5-5 for top/bottom constraints. I've also set the ViewMode to "Aspect Fit".

I've tried different setup :

1. set the height of UIImageView to a specific value :
   --> The width of the image is modify to keep the image ratio
2. don't set the height of UIImageView
   --> it considers that the height is equal to 0 and therefore doesn't even display the image
3. set the height greater or equal to a specific value :
   -- > same behavior as 1. (The width of the image is modify to keep the image ratio)

I'm loading the image from an URL so I've been using the lib Haneke (https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) with the following function :
imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url).

It has an automatic resize of the image and I don't know how to get the original width/height of the image to set the height manually.

Again, what I want is the picture to keep its ratio and to completely fill the width of the cell.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup I came up with. It's a quick and dirty demo, but I would assume you'd want the image to always be centered. You can set the Horizontal and Vertical Center Constraint in storyboard to always keep it centered
If you want it to always completely fill the view, you can replace `Equal Height` with `Equal Width`, but by doing so, the imageView will run off the screen on some sizes because of the aspect ratio constraint

[image: Autolayout Setup]

I've also included screenshots of the view at different sizes

[image: Any]

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Comment: thanks for your answer Sean.
Do you set Equal Width with which component? I've tried to select both my UIView and my UIViewImage but the checkbox for "Equal Width" is disabled.

Comment: And also, you set the Height to what value? As I said, If I don't put any height, it won't display the image at all

Comment: The imageView is set to be equal width with the superView. There's 2 ways I know for doing this. 1. cmd+click the imageView, then the superView, then you should be able to select `Equal Width` at the bottom of storyboard. 2. Right click on the imageView, hold and drag to the superView, and a popup should appear allowing you to choose `Equal Width`. For your second question, if you have the `Ratio` and `Equal Width` constraints set, autolayout should be able to know what size to display.

Comment: I've done exactly as you said, unfortunately, I have an error Missing Constraints for my UIImageView : "Need constraints for : Y position or height".
This is because I don't have an height specify for my Superview (as the height should be dynamic)

Comment: Here's said quick and dirty demo, let me know if it helps. https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2uytrwtfoycefc/AutolayoutDemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: Looks like it doesn't even match my requirements as I don't want to lose on the width, I want the width to be fix and to match the width of the screen. It's the height that should be dynamic.
But nevermind I'll just keep a fix height and crop the picture I guess. No other choice

Comment: Maybe what you want is to use `AspectFill` instead of `AspectFit` on your imageView