# Automatically update frames in autolayout

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I have imageview with Aspect Fit mode in my layout. Image is resizing well, but frame remain still big. Is there way to automatically update imageview frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aspect Ratios in storyboard. Right click on the imageView from on end to another end and a popup should show to allow you to select Aspect Ratio

Comment: When I right click on image I see this: http://i62.tinypic.com/9kbew3.png

Comment: But I've added aspect ratio constraint here: http://i61.tinypic.com/ank22s.png But still frames are bigger

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say right click and drag. I think I've also just answered a similar question a few minutes ago that might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119325/autolayout-keep-ratio-of-image-with-horizontal-constraints-swift-xcode-6/27136005#27136005

Comment: Look at that pic: http://i61.tinypic.com/nd0ept.png I want to have Image 8px from Label above, but there is bigger space. Even ratio didn't help.

Comment: I've done it in code, I set frame size after loading subviews, but I was wandering is there way to do this in layout

Comment: Could you share your `CGRect` when you set the frame in code?

Comment: (0.0,0.0,240.0,128.0)

In the previous post I've sent you wrong pic with contraints, here are this which work when I change frame in code:
http://i57.tinypic.com/xfqckm.png
        viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        var width = scrollView.frame.width-16
        widthConstrain.constant = width
        heightConstraint.constant = width*0.75;
        
Here is project with example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B586zrRNUPWOdV9VQUFZbE1peVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://www.dropbox.com/s/67alvszuijcxzg3/ImageTest.zip?dl=0